# How to extract all adjectives from a strings of text in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, nlp

I am loading a CSV into a pandas data frame. One of the columns in the dataframe is "reviews" which contain strings of text. I need to identify all the adjectives in this column in all the rows of the dataframe and then create a new column "adjectives" that contains a list of all the adjectives from that review.

I've tried using TextBlobs and was able to tag the parts of speech for each case using the code posted.

```py
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

df=pd.read_csv('./data.csv')

def pos_tag(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).tags
    except:
        return None

df['pos'] = df['reviews'].apply(pos_tag)

df.to_csv('dataadj.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there. `TextBlob(text).tags` returns a tuple list of (word, tag). You just need to filter based on the tag (`JJ` in your case).

You could do something like this:

```
def get_adjectives(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    return [ word for (word,tag) in blob.tags if tag == "JJ"]

df['adjectives'] = df['reviews'].apply(get_adjectives)
```

EDIT: To also capture ajectives at the comparative / superlative form (JJR/JJS), replacing `tag == "JJ"` with `tag.startswith("JJ")` should work.

Comment: Ah! I was so close. This worked perfectly. Thanks so much. Quick clarification -- Do I also need to add JJR and JJS in order to get the comparative and superlative adjectives or does JJ select them all?

Comment: Oh, actually you're right, this only captures adjectives not at the comparative or superlative form. Instead of `tag=="JJ"`, `tag.startswith("JJ")` would capture them all

Comment: How do we extract nouns and adjectives together using this code?